# Uploading PDFs to a directory PHP

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm uploading PDFs to a directory and my script works fine for one directory but I'm having troubles coming up with a way to write the script efficiently when I have more then one directory to upload PDFs on a page. I know of a few ways I can do it, like write another function like below but there must be a better way so I dont have to write out the whole script for every directory I want to upload PDFs to. Code below.

```
if(is_post_request()) {

$targetdirectory = "../../pathofdirectory/pdf/";
$targetdirectory = $targetdirectory . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']) ;

$file_type=$_FILES['file']['type'];

if ($file_type=="application/pdf") {

 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $targetdirectory))

 {

 $message = "The file ". basename( $_FILES['file']['name']). " is uploaded";

 }

 else {

 $message = "Problem uploading file";

 }
}

else {

 $message = "You may only upload PDFs.<br>";

}
    
}
```

And of course the simple form

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" size="50" />
    <input class="button common" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: What is the reason for using an alternate directory? What is the condition? Do you want users to choose which directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're okay with allowing users choosing which directory to upload to, you can give them the option.

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" size="50" />
    <select name="folderOption">
        <option value="1">First Folder</option>
        <option value="2">Second Folder</option>
        <option value="3">Third Folder</option>
    </select>
    <input class="button common" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Obviously, you would need to validate server-side for bad data.

```
if (is_post_request()) {
    $targetdirectory = "../../pathofdirectory/pdf/";
    $targetdirectory = $targetdirectory . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']) ;
    $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    $folderOption = $_POST['folderOption'];
    if ($folderOption == 1 || $folderOption == 2 || $folderOption == 3) {
        switch ($folderOption) {
            case 1:
                $targetdirectory = "../../pathofdirectory/pdf/";
                break;
            case 2:
                $targetdirectory = "../../pathofdirectory2/pdf/";
                break;
            case 3:
                $targetdirectory = "../../pathofdirectory3/pdf/";
                break;
            default:
                $targetdirectory = "../../pathofdirectory/pdf/";
        }
        if ($file_type == "application/pdf") {
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $targetdirectory)) {
                $message = "The file ". basename( $_FILES['file']['name']). " is uploaded";
            } else {
                $message = "Problem uploading file";
            }
        } else {
            $message = "You may only upload PDFs.<br>";
        }
    } else {
        $message = "Bad data received for directory choice.<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah yes this might just work for what I need, simple and nice. The page where one can upload to the directories is password protected, one has to be login as an admin so this would be ok. Thanks for answer!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. If there was a condition on the file, you could do it in code, but it's not bad to let users choose if that's the point of this.

Comment: This looks great. I was trying to figure out how to do the                                                 if ($folderOption == 1 || $folderOption == 2 || $folderOption == 3) {
        switch ($folderOption) {  (I'm getting an error with move_uploaded_file(): The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory in) I'll post a fix when I find it.

Comment: ah simple error... believe its just with the path of the directory. Nope that wasn't it :)

Comment: Nice. Yeah, make sure you use absolute paths in ubuntu. It makes it easier imo. Relative is fine, but you gotta calculate how many ../ 's you need.

Comment: Yeah its not the path. I know that $targetdirectory is putting out the correct path as I have echo it on submit. but the script seems to be stopping at if(move_uploaded_file. I'll get back.

Comment: Ahh I found it. So I just had to add the file name in the switch ($FolderOption) like so: $targetdirectory = "../../path/pdf/" . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']); Awesome!! Thanks again, this is much better than what I had!